# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application self-hosted on Azure AppService restarts accidentaly

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0, restart

Application contains couple of `IHostedService`s that run continiously.

**Diagnostics and solve problems** blade shows this:

[image]

I can't see any stop/restart messages in activity log. Stop message appears only if I stop service manually:

[image]

Application does not restart and `IHosted service`s run continiously as expected if deployed on local machine.
What can be the reason of unexpected restarts in Azure?